# Do I have to refactor our codes in order to do google test(unit test)?

Tags: unit-testing, dependency-injection, mocking, googletest

Basically when we developed, we didn't think about the unit test :(, so currently our codes structures are like:

```
//MyClass to be tested
#inculde "Dependency0.h"   //Production Class
#inculde "Dependency1.h"   //Production Class
...

MyClass
{
    MyClass(){}
    void myClassMethods()
   { 
       dependency0->func();
       dependency1->func();
   }

   Dependency0 *dependency0;  //Production Class
   Dependency1 *dependency1;  //Production Class
}
```

Based on my understanding of unit test & dependency injection, the more suitable code structure should be like:

```
//MyClass to be tested
#inculde "IDependency0.h"
#inculde "IDependency1.h"
...

MyClass
{
    MyClass(){}
    void myClassMethods(IDependency0 *IDep0, IDependency1 *IDep1)  
   { 

   }

}
```

IDependency0 is the interface of depency0

Most of our codes didn't follow the rule of test-driven-development... In this case do we have to refactor our codes? Alternatively is there a automated unit test tool?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in general, you need to rewrite your code to be testable if it was not written with testability in mind.

However, you may be able to limit code changes to places where classes are *defined* instead of also rewriting places where classes are *used*. This reduces a lot of work.

For example, you can use dependency injection in the constructor with default values:

```cpp
class SomeClass
{
public:
  SomeClass(IDependency* dependency = new Dependency())
    : m_dependency(dependency)
  {}

private:
  IDependency* m_dependency;
};
```

In this way, you do not have to change the way the class is used.

Another option is to use templates and default template parameters. As templates are a compile-time construct, it can give better run-time performance.